# How to pass a value to the CREATE function in a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, foreign-keys, constraints

How can I set a value that I have in my controller to my view to update this with that value into the database?

My controller functions:

```
 public ActionResult Create( [Bind(Prefix = "id")]int testid)
    {

        if (testid != 0)
        {
        ViewBag.sectionid = new SelectList(db.section, "id", "name");

        ViewBag.testid =new SelectList(db.test.Where(t => t.id == testid), "id", "name");

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View("mislukt");
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /TestSection/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(testsection testsection)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.testsection.Add(testsection);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.sectionid = new SelectList(db.section, "id", "name", testsection.sectionid);
        ViewBag.testid = new SelectList(db.test, "id", "name", testsection.testid);
        return View(testsection);
    }
```

my view :
    
        testsection

```
        <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.testid, "test")
         </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("testid", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.testid)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sectionid, "section")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("sectionid", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sectionid)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.mindifficulty)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.mindifficulty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.mindifficulty)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.maxdifficulty)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.maxdifficulty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.maxdifficulty)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.questioncount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.questioncount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.questioncount)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.weight)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.weight)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.weight)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

this works but gives me this:

[image: not good]

and I want this:

[image: want this]

I tried just using :

```
 ViewBag.testid = db.test.Where(t => t.id == testid);
```

and then just set this view:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
            @ViewBag.testid
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.testid)
        </div>
```

but I get a FK constraint when I do this.

Anybody know how I can get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting u correctly ....Try with textboxFor and make it readonly .

Comment: how do I link the ViewBag to it then?

Comment: you will not use ViewBag, instead you will assign the value to a property off your Model and use TextBoxFor associated with that property

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution although it is very bad! so if someone knows a better solution please let me know!!

what I now did is set the selected value of the dropdonwlist to 1 (since I only get 1 option due to the where-clause it always is the right value) and then I hide the dropdownlist from my view with javascript.

As I said very bad solution so please If you know how I can fix it properly let me know.

just to be clear I want to pass the testid from a another view to the createview(shown in the picture) and then write al the inputted values together with that testid to my database!